# A block staying at rest in a two-block system

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, free-body-diagram, spring

[image]

Let us assume a scenario where two blocks are connected by a spring and are at rest in a frictionless surface. If we give a velocity $v$ to one of the blocks, it will try to compress the spring. Then spring force $-kx$ will arise and will work on both the blocks. Hence the other block will also gain motion instantly towards the first block. But in many problems,i have seen that the the second block which was not given any velocity initially and was at rest,is assumed to be at rest throughout the time. And the surface was frictionless and the reference frame was not of the second block as well. But according to the above logic, both the blocks should have started motion. So i am really confused if i am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that the two blocks have the same mass as each other, which is $m$, and the spring has negligible mass.

If you give one of the blocks an initial velocity $v$ to the right then you give the whole system (the two blocks and the spring) a momentum of $mv$. Since there is no friction, this momentum must remain constant. So the centre of mass of the system, which is half way between the blocks, will move with a constant velocity $\frac v 2$ to the right (because the mass of the whole system is $2m$).

If we work in a reference frame in which this centre of mass is at rest, then initially the right hand block has velocity $\frac v 2$ and the left hand block has velocity $-\frac v 2$. By conservation of momentum, the velocities of the two blocks in this COM reference frame must always sum to $0$.

As the spring acts on the right hand block it will slow down until its velocity is $0$ (in the COM reference frame), then it will accelerate to the left until its velocity is $-\frac v 2$, then it will slow down again until its velocity is $0$, and then start accelerating to the right until its velocity is $\frac v 2$. It them repeats this cycle, which is simple harmonic motion.

The left hand block will also perform SHM in the COM reference frame, but half a cycle out of phase with the right hand block. So its initial velocity is $-\frac v 2$, it moves to the left and slows down until its velocity is $0$, then it accelerates to the right until its velocity is $\frac v 2$, then it slows down until its velocity is $0$, and finally it accelerates to the left until its velocity is $-\frac v 2$.

To see the motion of the blocks in the reference frame of the ground, you just add $\frac v 2$ to their velocities in the COM reference frame. So the right hand block starts with velocity $v$, decelerates to velocity $0$, then accelerates to velocity $v$ again. The left hand block starts with velocity $0$, accelerates to velocity $v$, then decelerates to velocity $0$ again. At any time the sum of the velocities of the two blocks is always $v$. In effect, the two blocks are passing momentum from one to the other and back again via the spring that joins them.